# Convert size_t to big endian on Linux

Tags: performance, c, linux, integer, bitwise

I see that on Linux there are various built-in functions to convert endianness for specific integer width types, and they are probably faster than anything one can write and compile on their own.  But I want to write a `size_t` (under Linux in C), which does not have a specified width, to big-endian array of bytes, as fast as possible.

Is this the fastest way?

```
#include <limits.h>

// write "from" to array of bytes "to" in big-endian fashion
void big_endian_size(unsigned char to[], size_t from) {

    unsigned char *p = to + (sizeof(size_t) - 1);

    while (1) {
        *p = from;

        if (to == p)
            break;

        p--;
        from >>= CHAR_BIT;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you're looking for performance then you should, at least, provide a specialized version for the most common cases:

```
void big_endian_size(uint8_t to[], size_t from) {
#if UINT32_MAX == SIZE_MAX
    // Specialization for 4 bytes size_t
#elif UINT64_MAX == SIZE_MAX
    // Same as above but for 8 bytes size_t
#else
    // Your current implementation...
#endif
}
```

*Specialized* versions may simply reuse this:

```
to[3] = from & 0x000000FF);
to[2] = (from & 0x0000FF00) >> 8;
// And so on...
```

Note that you may also simply return another `size_t` (instead of an array) with its bytes rotated. This will be considerably faster (also if implemented with a plain `for` to go through all bytes).

Also note that if you extract the 32 bit *swap* code into a separate function then you can use it both for 32 bit and 64 bit sizes (for example see byteswap.h for an implementation).

Do you need more? Assembly. For example on X86/X64 assembly you have `BSWAP` that does it in one instruction (I remember also ARM has but I don't remember the mnemonic), just check for target architecture to provide more and specialized versions.

Notes: Why `&`? Because truncation (let's imagine `uint8_t val = 0xffffffff >> 8`) is platform specific.

Comment: Well does not exactly work the way you wrote, for 8 bytes, you would want to compare `SIZE_MAX` with `UINT8_MAX`, not `ULONG_MAX`.  But thank you for this idea of comparing `SIZE_MAX`, I did not know it before.   And also, for using the preprocessor, as doing this at runtime would of course not work, due to overflow.

Comment: Oh, and I don't see why you need the `&`'s.  If you are sure you need it , please tell me why.  Second, I don't understand why you cast to a signed type.  Again, if you are sure, tell me why.

Comment: `SIZE_MAX` is the maximum VALUE you can store in `size_t`, what I'm doing there is checking if `size_t` is 4 bytes (it matches `uint32_t`maximum value) or 8 bytes. If you compare against UINT8_MAX then...you will never execute that code.

Comment: Casting can be omitted but compiler may/should emit a warning. I'm also using `&` to mask the value to the single byte I want to extract. It _might_ be unnecessary (because shifted value will be truncated) but then you're in the realm of implementation-defined code (conversion from bigger value to a smaller one) which should be avoided if possible.

Comment: `(uint8_t)(0xffff >> 8)` is neither undefined nor implementation defined. `(int)from` on the other hand is implementation defined and unnecessary to boot.

Comment: Don't stop to the 2nd byte. 0xffff00?

Comment: I still don't understand what you are saying about `UINT_MAX`.  You seem to be assuming that `int` is 4 bytes and `long` is 8 bytes, which is not necessarily true.  Also what you are saying is implementation-defined, is in fact not, it is perfectly well defined by the C standard.  Because unsigned overflow like this is well-defined, the compiler will not issue a warning.  Anyway, I don't want to argue.  What I wanted to see here, is there a better way.  And you told me about comparing `SIZE_MAX` which allows improvement.  If I "union" my best code and your best code, I get my answer.

Comment: @user I agree you should use UINT64_MAX to be platform independent. The other one is not overflow (which is well defined) but truncation which is implementation defined

Comment: Specialized versions...`to[0] = ((int)from) & 0x000000FF);` appears to be filling `to[]` in _little edian_ fashion.

Comment: `((int)from) & some_constant)` is a poor idea.  `(int)from` may narrow the value.

Comment: @chux ouch! You're right about ordering, fixed that. `int` was still there from code using `UINT_MAX`, my bad, updated. Thank you!

Comment: @AdrianoRepetti `(int32_t)` is no better than `(int)` as it may narrow the value too.  Perhaps you want something like `(from & 0x0000FF00u) >> 8;`  There is no reason for a cast to any signed type nor signed mask constant here.

Comment: AFAIK casting from unsigned to signed 32 bit integer won't narrow the value (but please correct me if I'm wrong!) and literal is already promoted to the proper type to hold that positive value. Hmmmm shouldn't just dropping the cast be enough?